# How to use CJK environment in footnote?

Tags: footnotes, cjk

I am writing a paper in English. But I'd like to have my name in Chinese displayed. I figured that it would be great to have it in the footnote. Here is what I was trying to do:

```
...
\usepackage{CJK}
...
\author{Xxxxx Xxxxx\footnote{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}Xxxxx, Xxxxx (某某某) is supported in part by U.S. taxpayers through NSF grant XXX-xxxxxxx.\end{CJK}}\footnotemark[1]}
...
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I got an error message when I tried to compile TeX to PDF.

> Latex Error: ./colorfulps.tex:45 Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
>   ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 45.
>   ! Emergency stop.

I tried to put the CJK environment in the body text, and it works just find. If I put the CJK environment in a footnote in the body text, I didn't get the error, but the Chinese characters didn't show up, either. So I am pretty sure this is something specific to footnote.

Is there a way to get around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you could turn this into a complete minimal (non-)working example, including a `\documentclass{}` and a `\title`, which is needed for `\maketitle` to work. This way people can just copy and paste the code into their editor and don't have to worry about that before being able to help you.

Comment: @Adam I am glad to be part of the community. And thanks for the suggestion! Definitely will do it next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work. `\footnotemark` goes first, `footnotetext` goes second. Also `CJKutf8` package is used here for the Chinese character to show up.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}         
\setcounter{footnote}{1}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@fnsymbol}{\@arabic{}}{}{}
\makeatother


\title{A project}
\author{Xxxxx Xxxxx\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]}
\footnotetext{
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}Xxxxx, Xxxxx (某某某) is supported in part by U.S. taxpayers through NSF grant XXX-xxxxxxx.
\end{CJK}}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}
%\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
%\end{titlepage}
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Jesse, thanks! Though the code is beyond my understanding, it works like a charm. However, if I add a lot of text after the title (after the last \end{CJK}), then the layout breaks down and the footnote seems to be outside of the page. Do you know how to remedy this issue?

Comment: If the title page is the only place you need to put in chinese. Then you can remove the cjk environment within \begin{document}...\end{document} because that is for chinese/english environment. By removing that out of the way, you are at pure English mode and maybe that is what you need.

Comment: I have removed the CJK environment within the document environment and I still have the same issue. Here is the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/Usu3mPo.jpg

Comment: Where did you put your text? Main text should not be before the `\begin{document}`. Second, activate the `begin/end{titlepage}` by removing the % out. Then put your main text after the `\end{titlepage}`

Comment: I put the main text after the last \end{CJK} inside the document environment. It is not before the \begin{document}. I know if I activate the begin/end{titlepage}, I can have a perfect footnote on the first page. However, I am not allowed to have a title page. And if I remove the titlepage environment, I get the PDF whose first page is shown in the image I posted.

Comment: OK, another workaround is to type some text in the begin/end titlepage in a sense that the footnote remains. Then type remaining text after  `\end{titlepage}` and add one line `\setcounter{page}{2}` to start page counting from 2 and thereafter. In such fashion, the titlepage serves as page 1 and the next page is page 2 and continue, thereafter, the normal counting.